# using json to store created 2 var items

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a small problem. I need to store specific information(a description and date) by using JSON. the current Javascript I have is:

```
    var main = function () {

    var dates = {};

    var addCommentFromInputBox = function () {
        var $newcomment

         if ($(".comment-input input").val() !== "") {
            $new_comment = $("<p>").text($(".comment-input input").val());
            if ($(".date-input input").val() !== "") {
                $new_date = $("<p>").text($(".date-input input").val());
            } else {
                $new_date = $("<p>").text("indetermined");
            }
            $new_date.hide();
            $new_comment.hide();
            $(".comments").append($new_comment);
            $(".date").append($new_date);
            $new_comment.fadeIn();
            $new_date.fadeIn();
            $(".comment-input input").val("");
            $(".date-input input").val("");
        } else {
            window.alert("Please fill in some text");
        }
    }; 

    $(".comment-input button").on("click", function (event) {
        addCommentFromInputBox();
    }); 

    $(".comment-input input").on("keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            addCommentFromInputBox();
        }
    });

    $(".date-input button").on("click", function (event) {
        addCommentFromInputBox();
    }); 

    $(".date-input input").on("keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            addCommentFromInputBox();
        }
    });

};
$(document).ready(main);
```

And now I need to store the created object to a server. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you try `dates.date=value; dates.description=desc;`. And then post the same json using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
var dates = [];
```

And initialize a date object like this:

```
date = {
    "date": "",
    "desc": ""
}
```

And fill in the values of the current object using:

```
date.date = value;
date.description = desc;
```

And add it to the original array like:

```
dates.push(date);
```

You can either send the single JSON to the server:

```
$.post(url, date, function (response) {});
```

Or, the entire array this way:

```
$.post(url, dates, function (response) {});
```

#### Snippet

```js
arrA = ["2014-01-01", "2014-02-14", "2014-05-01"];
arrB = ["New Year", "Valentine's Day", "May Day"];

var dates = [];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  date = {
    "date": "",
    "desc": ""
  }

  date.date = arrA[i];
  date.desc = arrB[i];

  dates.push(date);
}
console.log(dates);
```